# iText Fill Form / Copy Page to new Document

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I'm useing `iText` to fill a template PDF which contains a `AcroForm`.
Now I want to use this template to create a new PDF with dynamically pages.
My idea is it to fill the template PDF, copy the page with the written fields and add it to a new file. They main Problem is that our customer want to designe the template by them self. So I'm not sure if I try the right way to solve this Problem.

So I've created this code which don't work right now I get the error `com.itextpdf.io.IOException: PDF header not found.`

My Code

```
 x = 1;
try (PdfDocument finalDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("C:\\Users\\...Final.pdf"))) {
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : testValues) {
            String path1 = "C:\\Users\\.....Temp.pdf"
            InputStream template = templateValues.get("Template");

            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(path1);

            try (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(template), writer)) {
                PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
                for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> map2 : map.entrySet()) {

                    if (form.getField(map2.getKey()) != null) {
                        Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
                        fields.get(map2.getKey()).setValue(map2.getValue());


                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException | PdfException ex) {
                System.err.println("Ex2: " + ex.getMessage());

            }
            if (x != 0 && (x % 5) == 0) {
                try (PdfDocument tempDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path1))) {
                    PdfPage page = tempDoc.getFirstPage();
                    finalDoc.addPage(page.copyTo(finalDoc));

                } catch (IOException | PdfException ex) {
                    System.err.println("Ex3: " + ex.getMessage());

                }

            }
             x++;
       }
    } catch (IOException | PdfException ex) {
        System.err.println("Ex: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Part 1 - PDF Header is Missing

this appears to be caused by you attempting to re-read an InputStream w/in a loop that has already been read (and, depending on the configuration of the PdfReader, closed).  Solving for this depends on the specific type of InputStream being used - if you want to leave it as a simple InputStream (vs. a more specific yet more capable InputStream type) then you'll need to first slurp up the bytes from the stream into memory (e.g. a ByteArrayOutputStream) then create your PDFReaders based on those bytes.

i.e.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream templateBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((int c = template.read()) > 0) templateBuffer.write(c);
for (/* your loop */) {
    ...
    PdfDocument filledInAcroFormTemplate = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(templateBuffer.toByteArray())), new PdfWriter(tmp))
   ...
```

### Part 2 - other problems

Couple of things

1. make sure to grab the recently released 7.0.1 version of iText since it included a couple of fixes wrt/ AcroForm handling
2. you can probably get away with using ByteArrayOutputStreams for your temporary PDFs (vs. writing them out to files) - i'll use this approach in the example below
3. PdfDocument/PdfPage is in the "kernel" module, yet AcroForms are in the "form" module (meaning PdfPage is intentionally unaware of AcroForms) - IPdfPageExtraCopier is sortof the bridge between the modules.  In order to properly copy AcroForms, you need to use the two-arg copyTo() version, passing an instance of PdfPageFormCopier
4. field names *must* be unique in the document (the "absolute" field name that is - i'll skip field hierarcies for now).  Since we're looping through and adding the fields from the template multiple times, we need to come up with a strategy to rename the fields to ensure uniqueness (the current API is actually a little bit clunky in this area)

   ```
   File acroFormTemplate = new File("someTemplate.pdf");
   Map<String, String> someMapOfFieldToValues = new HashMap<>();
   try (
       PdfDocument  finalOutput = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("finalOutput.pdf")));
   ) {
       for (/* some looping condition */int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
           // for each iteration of the loop, create a temporary in-memory
           // PDF to handle form field edits.
           ByteArrayOutputStream tmp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           try (
               PdfDocument filledInAcroFormTemplate = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(acroFormTemplate)), new PdfWriter(tmp));
           ) {
               PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(filledInAcroFormTemplate, true);
               for (PdfFormField field : acroForm.getFormFields().values()) {
                   if (someMapOfFieldToValues.containsKey(field.getFieldName())) {
                       field.setValue(someMapOfFieldToValues.get(field.getFieldName()));
                   }
               }
               // NOTE that because we're adding the template multiple times
               // we need to adopt a field renaming strategy to ensure field
               // uniqueness in the final document.  For demonstration's sake
               // we'll just rename them prefixed w/ our loop counter
               List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
               fieldNames.addAll(acroForm.getFormFields().keySet()); // avoid ConfurrentModification
               for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
                   acroForm.renameField(fieldName, x+"_"+fieldName);
               }
           }

           // the temp PDF needs to be "closed" for all the PDF finalization
           // magic to happen...so open up new read-only version to act as
           // the source for the merging from our in-memory bucket-o-bytes
           try (
               PdfDocument readOnlyFilledInAcroFormTemplate = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(tmp.toByteArray())));
           ) {
               // although PdfPage.copyTo will probably work for simple pages, PdfDocument.copyPagesTo
               // is a more comprehensive copy (wider support for copying Outlines and Tagged content)
               // so it's more suitable for general page-copy use.  Also, since we're copying AcroForm
               // content, we need to use the PdfPageFormCopier
               readOnlyFilledInAcroFormTemplate.copyPagesTo(1, 1, finalOutput, new PdfPageFormCopier());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: i still don't fully get what you're trying to do w/ this though "if (x != 0 && (x % 5) == 0) "...but hopefully this example is a good enough starting point

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your Code. Just added yourcode to my for each Loops and get the same error. I've checked the numbers of Bytes in my template. In the first foreach Loop turn I've got around 80k Bytes, after the first round the size is 0. InputStream template = templateValues.get("Template");

Comment: yeah..i wasn't addressing that part.  But it sounds like you're trying to read a single InputStream multiple times then (which you obviously can't do...once you reach the end of stream in the first loop iteration, that InputStream is STILL at the end of the stream in the second iteration -- hence the stream read "fails").  You probably want to create new instances of the InputStream for each pass through the loop -- if you can't do that, then you probably need to slurp up the bytes into memory (i.e. another byteArrayOutputStream) and create your PDFReaders from that

Comment: actually...if you're InputStream is actually a FileInputStream you can probably a) configure the PDFReader for the "template" to not automaticaly close the InputStream (can't remember the exact method name...) and b) call `template.getFileChannel().position(0)` at the start of the loop

Comment: Got it fixed now I've got one last Problem. Im exporting user Information and adding them to the PDF. Each PDF page can contain 5 "rows" of users. This is why I use if (x != 0 && (x % 5) == 0) {}. I use this to say "Okey filled form with 5 users, create new page". Since the ByteArrayOutputStream tmp = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); is inside the Loop it get reinitialised evry Iteration. Means it just copies the last written data in my new file. I want that it writes inside the "tmp" until one page is done and then reinitialised it. Hope you understand me [Excuse my english]

Comment: hmmn...that sounds like a completely different problem.  Sounds like you want the "template" repeated a number of times across a single page (5 times per page)?  That's a much harder problem to solve.  The PDF graphics model doesn't really "flow" content - it draws it on a page-sized canvas.  So even if you had 5 instances of the form on a single page, they'd just overlay each other (because the position of the form on the page is "fixed").  If I'm right about the "repeat on a SINGLE page" part, let's create a new question to capture that

Comment: Hey, nice answer so far. i still have a question to your third point. I currently use the PDFSplitter and added the 'forms' artifact in my pom. Is there any way to use the PDFSplitter with the PdfPageFormCopier? I think its nice to have a Splitter.. but its kinda sad i get all the warnings when using it. Alternative would be to use the PdfPageFormCopier and copy it manually

Answer (score 0):

Close your PdfDocuments when you are done with adding content to them.

Comment: @Ovoxo please edit your question to show where you closed each `PdfDocument` instance. Samuel's hint is important: Without properly closing the documents before using the created document, your code cannot run but with closing them at the right time it should (if there is no external issue, e.g. a broken template).

Comment: he is closing the document...PdfDocument is Closable, so the try-with-resources block handles this.  Where does "x" come from though (and what is it used for?)  And on what doc is the PDFHeader error coming from?

Comment: added x. I use it to know when I should add a page. In my template I have 5 rows. so after every 5 rows i add a new page. Looks like this llne does the error try (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(template), writer)) {

Comment: lol...what that just sounds like "InputStream template = templateValues.get("Template")" isn't actually pointing to a PDF then.  That said, there are other errors (although unrelated to PDF Header) with this code..although it is close.  I'll try to post a complete example in a few minutes.

Comment: @jameygraham *"he is closing the document...PdfDocument is Closable"* - arg, right. And the error during `new PdfReader(template)` indeed indicates an error while reading the template.

Comment: My bad, used to working with explicit closing and only glanced at the question before answering, missing the exception part.